# Font Awesome stacked images in html list

Tags: html-lists, font-awesome

I'm trying to use Font Awesome stacked images in a list as described in the example page http://fontawesome.io/examples/

List:

```
<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i>List icons</li>
</ul>
```

Stacked images:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-camera fa-stack-1x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-ban fa-stack-2x text-danger"></i>
</span>
```

I can't get images aligned correctly, as you can see in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/uqL4aLyj/

Does anyone know how to get it aligned correctly?

Thank you in advance

Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the `.fa-stack` class applies a `height`, `width` and `line-height` of `2em` to the stacked set of icons. A quick way to ensure non-stacked icons are aligned with stacked icons is to treat your non-stacked icons as a one-icon stack themselves.

You can achieve this by changing your current markup of:

```html
<li>
  <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>
  text
</li>
```

To:

```html
<li>
  <span class="fa-stack">
    <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-stack-1x"></i>
  </span>
  text
</li>
```

[Modified JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uqL4aLyj/1/).

Comment: Thank you James, clean solution. Anyway I'm wondering if there's the possibility to keep the original width and height of the list by editing some css class

Answer (score 0):

The examples on the fontawesome page uses stacked images outside an ordered/unordered list. Separates them with a `<br>` tag.

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
First item<br>
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-camera fa-stack-1x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-ban fa-stack-2x text-danger"></i>
</span>
Second item
```